# Consumir API NEWSAPI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webapi

estoy queriendo consumir la api [NewsAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvsj3.png) desde una API en .NET, el problema es que no me esta reconociendo la ruta y no se si es un problema de codigo o de la API misma.

Les coloco mi codigo a continuacion abajo, si me explican una mejor forma de hacerlo o encuentran un error me ayudarian un monton

**Program.cs**

```
using newsapi_backend.Services;
using newsapi_backend.Services.Interfaces;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddScoped<INewsService, NewsService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**NewsController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using newsapi_backend.Services.Interfaces;

namespace newsapi_backend.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class NewsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly INewsService _newsService;

        public NewsController(INewsService newsService)
        {
            _newsService = newsService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetNews()
        {
            var news = await _newsService.GetNewsAsync();

            return Ok(news);
        }
    }
}
```

**NewsService.cs**

```
using newsapi_backend.Models;
using newsapi_backend.Services.Interfaces;

namespace newsapi_backend.Services
{
    public class NewsService : INewsService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public NewsService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<News>> GetNewsAsync()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=apikey");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<NewsResponse>();
                return result.Articles;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to retrieve news from NewsAPI. StatusCode={response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La interfaz del service solo tiene la implementacion del metodo nada mas.
**No coloco el apikey pero eso ya deben saber que es el token que da la pagina**

**Modelos**

**News**

```
namespace newsapi_backend.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**NewsResponse**

```
namespace newsapi_backend.Models
{
    public class NewsResponse
    {
        public IEnumerable<News> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda estoy atento, les agradezco, y si hay una forma mejor de hacerlo sera bienvenido. Con respecto a obtener el apikey del archivo appsetting.json, tambien lo hice, lo obtiene bien incluso la ruta base tambien lo obtengo bien, veo que la ruta me arma bien pero newsapi me sigue tirando un error Bad-Request

---

El response que recibo es esta

```
    {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, 
        Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, 
        Headers:{  Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 15:36:35 GMT  Connection: keep-alive  
        Cache-Control: no-cache  Pragma: no-cache  X-Cached-Result: false  
        CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC  
Report-To: {"endpoints": 
        [{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=mIZ0D%2FPc4qJtWNGdVX2rNjkYBgcBVaqO7mRg4ZQE9Wq23eZKFrVFChR6Uy4urmorlxxEYoOrAWwhgbS9pmg0Slpgm%2Bnqgw1sQQFgciVZ0aj417N4%2F6u9SCQfOH0v"}],
"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}  NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}  
Server: cloudflare  CF-RAY: 7af9306f8cbdba68-EZE  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  Content-Length: 156  Expires: -1}, Trailing Headers:{}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me envia el response body en swagger

```
    System.Exception: Failed to retrieve news from NewsAPI. StatusCode=BadRequest
   at newsapi_backend.Services.NewsService.GetNewsAsync() in C:\Users\aleja\OneDrive\Escritorio\Alejandro\Platzi\exercise-with-newsapi\newsapi-backend\newsapi-backend\Services\NewsService.cs:line 26
   at newsapi_backend.Controllers.NewsController.GetNews() in C:\Users\aleja\OneDrive\Escritorio\Alejandro\Platzi\exercise-with-newsapi\newsapi-backend\newsapi-backend\Controllers\NewsController.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7050
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
:method: GET
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Referer: https://localhost:7050/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Y esto el response header

```
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
 date: Wed,29 Mar 2023 16:03:40 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
Responses
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando veo la ruta que me arma, y consulto por Postman con la misma ruta que me arma el servicio en Postman si devuelve bien

Comment: La parte importante es *Bad-Request*. Eso quiere decir que la **ruta está correcta**, y que la petición llega al servidor, pero hay algo malo con la misma y el servidor no la puede procesar. Entonces no es que *no te reconozca la ruta*;  funciona en postman. Tienes que poner un breakpoint en la linea de `IsSuccessStatusCode` y revisar la respuesta del servidor para saber cuál es el problema.

Comment: Añadi una respuesta a tu comentario mas abajo podes ver la respuesta que recibo

Comment: Y dices que la url es EXACTAMENTE la misma que utilizas en Postman?

Comment: Si pero estoy hablando de esta url https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=apikey que uso en el Service si la coloco en Postman funciona, pero cuando lo quiero consultar desde el service no me trae nada y pasa eso que puse

Comment: cual es la linea 26... estas seguro que falla la llamada a la API????

Comment: La linea 26 de NewsService es esta 
throw new Exception($"Failed to retrieve news from NewsAPI. StatusCode={response.StatusCode}");

Y la linea 20 del Controller es esta
var news = await _newsService.GetNewsAsync();

Comment: No se si es la llamada a la api exactamente, porque la url de la api en el Service esta bien, porque cuando coloco la misma url en Postman funciona, no encuentro en que puede estar fallando exactamente, si me esta faltantando alguna configuracion o que puede ser

Comment: te dice que el error es en la linea 26 ;)... o sea, tu error es el throw, no la llamada.. hace debug y fijate que es lo que pasa por favor...

Comment: Elimine la linea del throw pero la llamada me viene vacia